# D3 line or area chart with series that cross over each other

Tags: excel, d3.js, charts, visualization, data-visualization

I'm trying to make a chart to visualize our product backlog over time. My idea is to show a line (a "series") for each work item, with each line having a width according to its estimate, and each line stacked on all the other work items that are ahead of it (as of each day). So on any given day, a line be at a Y-axis height representing how much work is ahead of it on the backlog.

The problem is that the ordering changes day by day, so I'd need to have the series cross over each other, and I haven't been able to find a charting tool that will let me do it.

(I'm trying to demonstrate the high-level "flow" of work items - the ones near the top of the queue will keep getting done, but the ones near the back of the queue will just sit there for a long time. New ones will be introduced periodically, and old ones will be canceled. I imagine the rendered chart will look like streaks of wind, if you will.)

Is there a way to do it in D3, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much any chart visualization that you can think of *can* be done with d3, it's just a matter of execution.

I'm not positive exactly what you're describing, but is it something like this [baby name chart](http://www.visualcinnamon.com/babynamesus)?

You can look through the [gallery](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) to see a lot of different examples of what is possible with d3.

Comment: I looked through the entire gallery and didn't find anything that seemed close. But that baby name chart is almost exactly it! Thank you!